# Controller Unit Test How do I mock RedisTemplate opsForValue with return type ValueOperations

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, redis, mocking

In my controller I have code like the following.
RedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate

```
def accessRedis()
{
   val = stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get('Key')
}
```

In my controller Test, I intent to inject a mocked RedisTemplate that return a mocked ValueOperations. My code:

```
def template = mockFor(RedisTemplate)       
def val = mockFor(org.springframework.data.redis.core.ValueOperations)
val.demand.get {p-> println "$p"}
template.demand.opsForValue {
    return val.createMock()
}

controller.stringRedisTemplate = template.createMock()
controller.accessRedis()
```

However, I got the following error:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.tnd.viewport.ui.AppHawkControllerSpec$_$spock_feature_0_1_closure2@1aa55dd5' with class 'com.tnd.viewport.ui.AppHawkControllerSpec$_$spock_feature_0_1_closure2' to class 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.ValueOperations'

Could you advice a solution for my scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. Mock them separately.

Eg.

```
@MockBean
private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;
@MockBean
private ValueOperations valueOperations;


@Test
public void testRedisGetKey() {
    // This will make sure the actual method opsForValue is not called and mocked valueOperations is returned
    doReturn(valueOperations).when(redisTemplate).opsForValue();

    // This will make sure the actual method get is not called and mocked value is returned
    doReturn("someRedisValue").when(valueOperations).get(anyString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
redisTemplate = mock(RedisTemplate.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(loginService, "redisTemplate", redisTemplate);

 List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(15l);
        List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        keys.addAll(Arrays.asList("15"));

HashOperations<Serializable, Object, Object> hashOperations =mock(HashOperations.class);

when(redisTemplate.opsForHash()).thenReturn(hashOperations);
        when(hashOperations.multiGet(anyString(), anyListOf(Object.class))).thenReturn(list);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to make your answer better understandable.